# A reminder/memo file at login in Unix Solaris

Tags: unix

I want that a user gets a specific message on the screen when login in, which file should I update ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps provide examples, same message for each user, different message for each user, what kind of information in the message, etc.

Comment: Or at least clarify that the message is **user**-specific; simply **specific** is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Its the message of the day, located at `/etc/motd`. The Solaris page about this file is located [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7229/sysressysinfo-20988/index.html), on Oracle's website.

**Edit:**
If you want a user-specific message, one way to do it would be to edit that person's .kshrc or .bashrc (can check /etc/passwd to get the user's shell) and then put a message into ~.bashrc or ~.kshrc or whatever to display on login.

Comment: The answer does not meet the requirements. /etc/motd is not user-specific.

Comment: That seemed unclear to me, but I guess the wording is strange. I wouldn't have assumed it was a different message per user. They should probably edit the question to be more clear if that's what they want. "A specific message" doesn't necessary mean different for each user, could just mean different from the standard.